# Binary Search in Python 2 variable not updating causing an infinite loop.....why is the variable not updating?

Tags: python, search, binary

This is my binary search. The mid does not update and it loops infinitely.

```
def binary_search (z, A, start, end):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        mid = start + (end - start) / 2
        if (z < A[mid]) and (z > A[mid-1]):
            return A[mid-1]
        elif (z < A[mid]):
            return binary_search(z, A, start, mid)
        elif (z > A[mid]):
            return binary_search(z, A, mid, end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def binary_search (z, A, start, end):
    if end < start:
        return None
    else:
        mid = start + (end - start) / 2
        if (z < A[mid]):
            return binary_search(z, A, start, mid-1)
        elif (z > A[mid]):
            return binary_search(z, A, mid+1, end)
        else: 
            return mid
```

I changed a couple of things around.

I check first changed `end < start:` because `if len(A) == 0:` will stay constant and won't allow you to use it as a base case.

Also, you when you a returning the binary search you need to skip the mid value, because that's the one you are returning.

**I tested the code and it works!**